# Текстовый редактор HTML на основе Windows Forms. Как уменьшить расстояние между строк? - C#

Tags: c#, html, css, winforms

Как уменьшить расстояние между строк?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Исходный проект+описание - [ссылка](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15559/A-Windows-Forms-based-text-editor-with-HTML-output)
Проект(дублирую) - [ссылка](http://transfiles.ru/yibji)

**РЕШЕНИЕ 1**. Не работает.
Решение, которое на мой взгляд подходит это заменить html код страницы загрузки, которая подставляется в браузер(webBrowser1) при старте приложения на код со стилем расстояния между строк.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Исходный код**

```
webBrowser1.DocumentText = "<html><body></body></html>";
```

**Исправленный**

```
webBrowser1.DocumentText = "<html><head> <style>  p, h1, h2, h3 {margin: 0; padding: 0} </style></head><body><p>Строка 291_1</p><p>Строка 291_2</p></body></html>";
```

**РЕШЕНИЕ 2**. Не работает.
Изменил HTML код

```
/// <summary>
        /// Add document body, turn on design mode on the whole document, 
        /// and overred the context menu
        /// </summary>
        static string docText = @"<!DOCTYPE html>   
<html><head> <style>  p, h1, h2, h3 {margin: 0; padding: 0} </style>    
<style>
p {
    line-height: 0.7;
}   

</style>    
</head><body><p>Строка 291_1</p><p>Строка 291_2</p></body></html>   
";

        private void SetupBrowser()
        {
            webBrowser1.DocumentText = docText;
            // webBrowser1.DocumentText = "<html><body></body></html>"; // исходный вариант строки
            doc =
            webBrowser1.Document.DomDocument as IHTMLDocument2;
            doc.designMode = "On";
            webBrowser1.Document.ContextMenuShowing += 
                new HtmlElementEventHandler(Document_ContextMenuShowing);
        }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: [Как задать хороший вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @tym32167 Спасибо за замечание. Но что не так с моим вопросом? Буду признателен если поможете расставить нужные акценты

Comment: Постараюсь пояснить, что не так: 1) вы скинули просто ссылку на пачку вашего кода, куда никто не будет смотреть. Если у вас есть проблема, нужно в вопрос вставлять (а не кидать ссылки) только необходимый для воспроизведения проблемы код. Это называется [минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: 2) В вопросе надо указать, как вы сами пытались решить проблему. Потому как если вы это не пытались сделать, то зачем кому то пытаться вам помогать?

Comment: основной посыл в том, что тем, как вы оформили вопрос сейчас, вы показываете, что совсем не постарались для тех людей, что будут его читать. А если вы не уважаете время других, оформляя таким образом вопрос, то никто не будет тратить своё время даже на то, чтобы ваш вопрос дочитать до конца.

Comment: @tym32167 Внёс изменения в вопрос

Comment: Так у вас html и вам в нем надо уменьшить расстояние между строк? Добавьте в теги html и css. И поглядите также [сюда](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_line-height.asp) ([пример](https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_line-height))

Comment: @tym32167 Я сделал так. См. скрин по ссылке. http://prntscr.com/jhosof . Правильно? Но не работает.

Comment: Я не вижу никаких картинок/файлов ссылки на которые вы постите, мне файерволл не позволяет. Также все, что вы делете, что пробуете, добавляйте в вопрос

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Берем текст из [примера](https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_line-height)

```
static string docText = @"<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
p.small {
    line-height: 0.7;
}

p.big {
    line-height: 1.8;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<p>
This is a paragraph with a standard line-height.<br>
The default line height in most browsers is about 110% to 120%.<br>
</p>

<p class=""small"">
This is a paragraph with a smaller line-height.<br>
This is a paragraph with a smaller line-height.<br>
</p>

<p class=""big"">
This is a paragraph with a bigger line-height.<br>
This is a paragraph with a bigger line-height.<br>
</p>

</body>
</html>";
```

Создаем форму с ним

```
public class MyForm : Form
{
    public MyForm()
    {
        this.Width = 500;
        this.Height = 500;

        var wb = new WebBrowser();
        wb.Width = 500;
        wb.Height = 500;


        this.Controls.Add(wb);

        wb.DocumentText = docText;
    }
}
```

Запускаем форму

```
new MyForm().ShowDialog();
```

Получаем

[image: форма]

Как видите, все работает. Почему не работает у вас - разбирайтесь с вашими стилями.

Если взять то, что было приведено в вопросе, и добавить туда стиль, показанный выше

```
static string docText = @"<!DOCTYPE html>   
<html><head> <style>  p, h1, h2, h3 {margin: 0; padding: 0} </style>    
<style>
p {
    line-height: 0.7;
}   

</style>    
</head><body><p>Строка 291_1</p><p>Строка 291_2</p></body></html>   
";
```

То получится

[image]

**UPD**

Перечитал вопрос. Заметил вот это

```
doc.designMode = "On";
```

Чем бы оно не было, оно полностью переписывает документ (по крайней мере для меня). Пришлось добавить стиль таким образом:

```
public class MyForm : Form
{
    public MyForm()
    {
        this.Width = 500;
        this.Height = 500;

        var wb = new WebBrowser();
        wb.Width = 500;     
        wb.Height = 500;        

        wb.DocumentCompleted += async (sender, args) => 
        { 
            var doc = wb.Document.DomDocument as IHTMLDocument2;            
            doc.designMode = "On";

            while (doc.readyState != "complete")
            {
                await Task.Delay(100);              
            }

            var stylesheet = doc.createStyleSheet();
            stylesheet.addRule("p", "line-height: 0;");
        };

        wb.DocumentText = string.Empty;
        this.Controls.Add(wb);      
    }
}
```

Ожидать приходится, так как после перехода в design mode документу надо время прогрузиться. 
Результат:

[image]

Comment: В приложении, которое размещено в вопросе не работает. Не понимаю..

Comment: @user9776818 обновил на то, что вы привели в вопросе

Comment: Прошу прощения, но не работает. Может я что-то не так делаю? После отладки - скрин. http://prntscr.com/jhqr2s  Гиф https://ibb.co/iMd4bJ

Comment: @user9776818 Я не вижу никаких картинок/файлов ссылки на которые вы постите, мне файерволл не позволяет. Также все, что вы делете, что пробуете, добавляйте в вопрос

Comment: добавил в вопрос изменения по последнему решению

Comment: @user9776818 обновил ответ